# Window 8.1 Volume keeps changing after releasing keyboard volume keys

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, sound-card, logitech-keyboard

I recently upgraded my PC from Windows 7 to 8.1.

When I tap the reduce/increase volume keys on my Logitech [Media Keyboard Elite](http://www.logitech.com/de-de/support/183), Windows keeps reducing/increasing the volume as if I was holding the key the whole time. The only way to stop it from doing this is to restart the computer.

When I first noticed the problem I installed the Logitech Keyboard software but that didn't change anything. I also tried to deactivate the automatic Communication volume change of Windows but that didn't help.

My sound card is the [Creative Sound Blaster Titanium](http://www.amazon.de/Creative-Sound-Blaster-Titanium-PCI-Express/dp/B001E5PJ2Y) and I have the newest software suite + drivers installed for that.

How can I fix this? I would really like to use my keyboards volume keys and the little window that is shown when changing the volume is in the way when it is shown permanently.

Comment: I would make sure the drivers for both devices specifically list Windows 8.1 as being supported

Comment: The sound card driver lists 8.1 support. The keyboard driver only lists Windows 8, but no Logitech products lists 8.1 specifically. Also the problem was already present before I installed the Logitech configuration software.

Comment: I just found out that I can stop the key from being pressed by disconnecting the keyboard physically and connecting again. The keyboard itself works fine on other computer though. Nobody knows anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference. The culprit was actually the mainboard. I have a MSI Z97 GAMING 9 and it seems the early BIOS versions of this mainboard had a bug in the USB keyboard support. After an update to the newest BIOS version everything works as expected.